# Return zero if value less than zero

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to return zero if a value is less than zero without using a case statement?

e.g. Max(a, 0) <-- 'Max' doesn't exist.

I would like my code to be as succinct as possible.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a case expression. This is pretty much what they were made for.

Comment: Its in the question!

Comment: What's in the question?

Comment: Why is "as succinct as possible" a goal? A `CASE` expression is self-documenting, and you don't get bonus points or improved performance from saving characters to land at something quite probably more cryptic.

Comment: @Sean he's saying "I do not want to use a case expression" because "I would like my code to be as succinct as possible."

Comment: evidently $$ = 1/LOC

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think one gets bonus points for saving characters if the result is not more cryptic. MAX(value, 0) is arguable more clear than CASE WHEN value < 0 THEN 0 ELSE  value END.

Comment: @Ian Sorry, but `MAX(value, 0)` does not convey to me that negative values will be thrown out in favor of `0`. The `CASE` expression says so explicitly.

Comment: 0 is greater than any negative value.  MAX(value, 0) is pretty clear to me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, its not as explicit, but it I believe its fairly commonly used outside of SQL.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
DECLARE @a INT = -3
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF (ABS(@a), -@a), 0)
```

This post just hints in the direction that a `CASE` expression is a much better option to get the expected result.

`NULLIF` is, after all, just a fancy `CASE`. The example query above expands (in the execution plan) to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN abs([@a])=( -[@a]) 
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE abs([@a]) 
        END IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN abs([@a])=( -[@a]) 
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE abs([@a]) 
        END 
    ELSE (0) 
END
```

A suitable `CASE` expression:

```
-- All versions
SELECT CASE WHEN @a > 0 THEN @a ELSE 0 END;

-- SQL Server 2012 or later
SELECT IIF(@a > 0, @a, 0);
```

Comment: @PaulWhite: so another reason to use this simple version: `SELECT CASE WHEN @a < 0 THEN 0 ELSE @a END`

Comment: An alternative expression that handles NULLs: `@A * ( ( Sign( @A ) + 1 ) / 2 )`